# Bootstrap - Columns nest error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've made a simple website using bootstrap. The template is very simple, I have 2 columns, the big one on the center and the sidebar on the right. In the center, under the big box, there are 2 more columns which are inside another row. (If you visit the website you'll see what I'm talking about)

Now... Basically the problem is that whenever I fill the main box with something making its height exceed the height of the sidebar the container moves a bit to the left. (If you try to click at the 'LAVORI' link, you'll see the container move)

LINK: http://jonathanmagnis.altervista.org/

Comment: it's because a scrollbar appears

Comment: Yeah it's that the problem! I didn't notice it because my desktop doesn't show the full website.

I solved this with this:

html {
      overflow-y: scroll;
}
Thank you very much!